# Where does the mysql server store the connections made by workbench?

Tags: mysql

There is a log in mysql server, where it keeps the log of connections made via workbench?

Answer (score 2):

The "[general log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html)" stores *all* queries, including connections.

Comment: Thanks Akina, I am not really interested in seeing the queries, what interests me is to know if someone other than me, uses the administrator to move the data directly on the database manager

Comment: Turn it on; see if it has what you need.